# HTTP::Proxy: how to forbid some domain

Tags: perl, http-headers, http-proxy

I'm using [HTTP::Proxy](http://search.cpan.org/~book/HTTP-Proxy-0.25/lib/HTTP/Proxy.pm) but I'm not able to understand how to make it fail for certain domain.

Here is some code.

```
use HTTP::Proxy;
use HTTP::Proxy::BodyFilter::simple;
use HTTP::Proxy::HeaderFilter::simple;
use Getopt::Long;

my $port = 3128;
my $fail_at;

my $ret = GetOptions ( "port=i" => \$port,
            "fail=s" => \$fail_at );

my @fail_at = split(/,/, $fail_at);

my $proxy = HTTP::Proxy->new;
$proxy->port( $port );

my $fail_filter = HTTP::Proxy::HeaderFilter::simple->new(
        sub { $_[1]->header( HEADERS_HERE ); }
);

foreach my $url (@fail_at) {
    $proxy->push_filter(
        host => $url,
        response => $fail_filter
    );
}

$proxy->start;
```

Can you please help me to understand what I have to write in place of HEADER_HERE?
I tried with `Status => '403 Forbidden'` but it didn't work. I'm able to modify every line of the http response, but the first.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [method `code` in `HTTP::Response`](http://p3rl.org/HTTP%3a%3aResponse#r-code).

```
use HTTP::Status qw(HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
⋮
my $fail_filter 
  = HTTP::Proxy::HeaderFilter::simple->new(sub {
    $_[2]->code(HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
});
```